# Correct sql lite syntax

Tags: sql, cordova

I am successfully adding a table to an sql lite database but I am struggling with the syntax to write values to the table,  please take a look at the code below and advice me on the correct syntax.

Sorry Code!

```
 var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "GBA", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    // Populate the database
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vehiclecheck');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vehiclecheck (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, checkfield VARCHAR(12), class INTEGER)');

       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO vehiclecheck (checkfield, class) VALUES (' + 'Test' + ',' + 1 + ')');
```

Comment: *cough*... you forgot the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this insertion

```
tx.executeSql("insert into vehiclecheck(checkfield, class) values(?,?)",["Test",'1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape Test. If you consider your SQL:

INSERT INTO vehiclecheck (checkfield, class) VALUES (Test,1)

You can see the single quotes around Test are missing.

Don't forget that you can use bound params as well. An example is here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/10/20/Example-of-PhoneGaps-Database-Support